# How to authenticate to the server over a secure connection to send mail from a script?

Tags: authentication, scripting, email, security

My current script uses this simple command:

```
mail -s "$my_msg" username\@mycompany.com </dev/null
```

When changing it to use a mailing list rather than the hardcoded username:

```
mail -s "$my_msg" mailing_list_1\@groups.mycompany.com </dev/null
```

It produces:

> 550 Unrouteable address

I need to be able to authenticate to the server over a secure connection.
How do I do this?

> Linux version 2.6.26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) is an SMTP client:

> TLS/SSL both in SMTP-over-SSL mode and
>   in STARTTLS mode. Full certificate
>   trust checks can be performed. A
>   client certificate can be sent.